# Usage of fmemopen

Tags: c, linux, stream

I don't understand an example of `fmemopen` from *APUE*

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BSZ 48

int
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[BSZ];

    memset(buf, 'a', BSZ-2);
    buf[BSZ-2] = '\0';
    buf[BSZ-1] = 'X';
    if ((fp = fmemopen(buf, BSZ, "w+")) == NULL)  //"w+" truncate the file by setting the first byte to null byte
        printf("fmemopen failed\n");
    printf("initial buffer contents: %s\n", buf); //print nothing cause the first byte is null byte.
    fprintf(fp, "hello, world"); //write format string to the stream, so the buffer should change and be rewritten.
    printf("before flush: %s\n", buf); //should print "hello, world". Why not?
    fflush(fp);
    printf("after fflush: %s\n", buf);
    printf("len of string in buf = %ld\n", (long)strlen(buf));

    memset(buf, 'b', BSZ-2);
    buf[BSZ-2] = '\0';
    buf[BSZ-1] = 'X';
    fprintf(fp, "hello, world");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("after  fseek: %s\n", buf);
    printf("len of string in buf = %ld\n", (long)strlen(buf));

    memset(buf, 'c', BSZ-2);
    buf[BSZ-2] = '\0';
    buf[BSZ-1] = 'X';
    fprintf(fp, "hello, world");
    fclose(fp);
    printf("after fclose: %s\n", buf);
    printf("len of string in buf = %ld\n", (long)strlen(buf));

    return(0);
}
```

I use Clion to debug and when it finishes `fprintf(fp, "hello, world");` and comes to `printf("before flush: %s\n", buf);`, I see **the content of char array `buf` does not change and print nothing**. Why!?

A debug screenshot for better description:

[image]

Also, quoted from the book:

> Third, a null byte is written at the current position in the stream whenever we
>   increase the amount of data in the stream’s buffer and call `fclose`, `fflush`, `fseek`,
>   `fseeko`, or `fsetpos`.

What does this mean?

---

Update:

From the book and it seems that *buffer is unchanged until stream is flushed* is the expected result.

[image]

Comment: I get `before flush: hello, world`.

Comment: I get that on Mac, but it's empty on Linux. I guess different C libraries do it differently.

Comment: @Barmar I got `_fmemopen` symbol not found on Mac... Linker error.

Answer (score -2):

change the allocated buf array in the stack

```
char buf[BSZ];
```

to this

```
char* buf = new(std::nothrow) chr[BSZ];
```

and freed buf after close the stream

delete[] buf

and test again.

Comment: This fails with various syntax errors: C ≠ C++. Besides, the original code is fine and this is unrelated to the question.

Comment: related to the question, Because buf must be allocated in HEAP , not in STACK

Comment: No, that is incorrect. There’s no reason why the memory couldn’t be stack-allocated.